# Adding a Term Count based on how many records and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following:
Customer ID, MDN, Plan, StartDate, EndDate, Term, Term Count, SMS Usage, Voice Usage

There may be records where a customer id shows up once or more -

If there is only one instance of that customer ID, i want term count to be 1 -

if the customer id shows up more than once, I want to order all the records by start date - and increment the term count for each record that is there ordered by start date -

If the customer id is 34, and the start dates and 1/1/2012 and 2/2/2012

the first one should be set to 1, the second should be set to 2 -

Sas

Answer (score 3):

Since we now know this is SQL Server 2008, not SQL Server 2000 as originally tagged, we can do this:

```
SELECT CustomerID, StartDate, TermCount = ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY StartDate)
  FROM dbo.table
  ORDER BY CustomerID, StartDate;
```

**EDIT** adding an update query based on new information on the shifting requirements.

```
;WITH t AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID, StartDate, CountColumn, TermCount = ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY StartDate)
      FROM dbo.table
) UPDATE t SET CountColumn = TermCount;
```

However as I suggested in the comment, this is not wise, since you will need to constantly update the entire table (or at least the entire set of rows for a customer) whenever any row for that customer changes. Just create a view based on the above `SELECT` query instead of trying to store the data.

---

Leaving a 2000 workaround here in case other users come across the same problem and are still running SQL Server 2000 for some reason. This is going to be very slow if your table is large.

```
SELECT CustomerID, StartDate, TermCount = (
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.table AS t2 
   WHERE t.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID 
   AND t.StartDate <= t2.StartDate
)
FROM dbo.table AS t
ORDER BY CustomerID, StartDate;
```

Comment: im running SQL server 2008 - sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Sarfaraz so why have you been tagging as SQL Server 2000? That's two questions now where extra work was performed because you said you were on SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I have to look closer, I thought I selected sql server 2008 both times! -

Comment: Why would you want to store this information statically? You can always derive it from the above query, and this avoids you have to update the entire table *every* time you update, delete or insert a single row.